# How to change current directory to another directory

Tags: php, file, include, directory

[image]

I want to include/upload some files from current directory to another directory as image shows. If i do this

```
    1. $currdir = getcwd();      
    2. chdir('/home');
    3. echo '<br/>'.getcwd();       
    4. chdir('/home/second/');
    5. echo '<br/>'.getcwd();       
    6. $dirs = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir');
    7. print_r($dirs);
    8. chdir($currdir);
```

It's show subdirectory list properly

But if i change line 4 to chdir('/home/**first**/');
  It give me empty array.

How i can read/include/upload files from directory structure like this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the

```
chdir('../home/second/');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use function called as system('Cd /home/First/Publich_Html');
Or 
chdir('../home/second/');